# Liner interpolation of missing data values of values

Tags: r, dataframe, interpolation

I have the following example dataframe (that will be converted later on to time series):

```
29/12/2014 8:00 0.010
29/12/2014 9:00 0.020
29/12/2014 11:00    0.060
1/1/2015 0:00   1.490
```

As can be seen there are values for every hour. I would like to find the missing hours such as 29/12/2014 12:00, 29/12/2014 13:00 till 31/12/2014 23:00  and to divide the (1.490 - 0.060) into the number of missing hours (48 + 12 = 60) and to add the missing lines and their values. The required result would be the addition of the following lines in their right location (there might be additional places in this dataframe where lines are missing): 
(please notice that the last value of 1.490 will be converted into the average value)

```
**29/12/2014 11:00  0.060**
29/12/2014 12:00 0.024
29/12/2014 13:00 0.024
29/12/2014 14:00 0.024
29/12/2014 15:00 0.024
29/12/2014 16:00 0.024
29/12/2014 17:00 0.024
29/12/2014 18:00 0.024
29/12/2014 19:00 0.024
29/12/2014 20:00 0.024
29/12/2014 21:00 0.024
29/12/2014 22:00 0.024
29/12/2014 23:00 0.024
30/12/2014 00:00 0.024
....
30/12/2014 23:00 0.024
31/12/2014 00:00 0.024
....
31/12/2014 23:00 0.024
**1/1/2015 0:00 0.024**
```

Comment: Pretty strange your desired result. In linear interpolation, the values of the second column should constantly grow starting from 0.060 by 0.024 and reaching eventually  1.490. The values should have been 0.084, 0.108, 0.132 and so on.

Comment: Thanks @nicola. The values are already deltas. So they are growing if you add them. When they are missing there is a need for this interpolation.